# wpsc purchase button not working on checkout page in IE

Tags: php, wordpress, e-commerce

Not really sure where to start, the site works well in all browsers except Internet Explorer

Here is the URL https://bonaccord.co.nz/shop/checkout/

I have been looking for answers everywhere but have not come close to finding a solution, most of the forums are unanswered.

It looks like the button does nothing when clicked? I am not sure as to why this would be as I have another site with the exact same button that does work.

URL for working purchase button http://www.odarid.co.nz/dev/checkout/

I thought it could be to do with the recently installed SSL but when disabled the button still does not work

Also when using the developer tools in IE I get this message

Object doesn't support this property or method

The code it refers to is

```
jQuery("form.product_form").livequery(function(){
    product_id = jQuery('input[name="product_id"]',this).val();
    image_element_id = 'product_image_'+product_id;
    jQuery("#"+image_element_id).data("product_id", product_id);
    parent_container = jQuery(this).parents('div.product_view_'+product_id);
    jQuery("div.item_no_image", parent_container).data("product_id", product_id);
});
```

I then tried disabling the scripts I wrote to see if they were causing problems with the wp-ecommerce js but still got the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

In the end I recopied the wpsc-shopping_cart_page.php to my theme and noticed that it was different to wpsc-shopping_cart_page.php I had originally.

Looks like after updating the wpsc plugin some of the template files changed so I had to re-style the new template.